# problem with creating bootable sd-card for PandaboardES

Tags: boot, arm

I have followed instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/ to write the image for Ubuntu 12.04. I had already done this before once in the past but with 11.10 Ubuntu sever Ed. Now I would like to write the 12.04 version because is supposed to run fine with [OpenFrameworks](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/). I have some problems with my SD-card reader also (maybe is not a very good one??) and can't follow the instructions listed, id est:

```
zcat ./ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gz |sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdb ; sudo sync
```

But instead I have to use this:

```
sudo sh -c 'zcat ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gzz > /dev/sdb' sync
```

That is more comfortable because I have an output on the screen. But the problem is when I plug the SD-card into my Pandaboard and start Minicom. this is my output:

```
walter@walter-RC530-RC730:~/Scrivania$ sudo minicom -s
```

```
Welcome to minicom 2.5

OPTIONS: I18n                                                                
Compiled on May  2 2011, 10:05:24.                                           
Port /dev/ttyUSB0                                                            

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys                                      


U-Boot SPL 2011.12 (Apr 02 2012 - 18:13:04)                                  
Texas Instruments OMAP4460 ES1.1                                             
OMAP SD/MMC: 0                                                               
reading u-boot.img                                                           
reading u-boot.bin                      
mkimage signature not found - ih_magic = ea000014
Assuming u-boot.bin ..                  
reading u-boot.bin                      


U-Boot 2011.12 (Apr 02 2012 - 18:13:04)

CPU  : OMAP4460 ES1.1
Board: OMAP4 Panda                                                              
I2C:   ready                                                                    
DRAM:  1 GiB                                                                    
WARNING: Caches not enabled                                                     
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0                                                           
Using default environment                                                       

In:    serial                                                                   
Out:   serial                                                                   
Err:   serial                                                                   
Net:   No ethernet found.                                                       
checking for preEnv.txt                                                         
reading preEnv.txt                                                              

** Unable to read "preEnv.txt" from mmc 0:1 **                                  
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0                                                
reading uEnv.txt                                                                

** Unable to read "uEnv.txt" from mmc 0:1 **                                    
reading boot.scr                                                                

293 bytes read                                                                  
Loaded script from boot.scr                                                     
Running bootscript from mmc0 ...                                                
## Executing script at 82000000                                                 
reading uImage                                                                  

4434784 bytes read                                                              
reading uInitrd                                                                 

6608373 bytes read                                                              
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80000000 ...                             
   Image Name:   Ubuntu Kernel                                                  
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)                          
   Data Size:    4434720 Bytes = 4.2 MiB                                        
   Load Address: 80008000                                                       
   Entry Point:  80008000                                                       
   Verifying Checksum ... OK                                                    
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 81600000 ...                       
   Image Name:   Ubuntu Initrd                                                  
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)                      
   Data Size:    6608309 Bytes = 6.3 MiB                                        
   Load Address: 00000000                                                       
   Entry Point:  00000000                                                       
   Verifying Checksum ... OK                                                    
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK                                                  
OK                                                                              

Starting kernel ...                                                             

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

After those lines nothing happens .... normally should begin the customization process, but never happens. Anyone can give my advice? Honestly I did this not so many times, so maybe I forgot something or made something wrong. Maybe my SD-card reader does not work properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get it working? I would like to know a few more details of the same so that I can get a better idea.

Share the environment variable values in boot using 'printenv'. Share the data in preEnv.txt. Above all, I would like to know the output in the Display of Pandaboard.

Answer (score 0):

Relative to the pre-installed images, it is sometimes more worthwhile to go through the instructions at ELinux.org to [create a netinstall image instead](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Method_2%3a_Use_the_NetInstall_method) to set up Edubuntu or whatever flavor you would like.  That's the work-around I had to follow with my BeagleBoard as the pre-installed 12.04 image booted great but then accepted no keyboard or mouse input from me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have led blinking continuosly.
2. If yes: Then you should just connect your Keyboard and HDMI display to the board.

Worked for me.
For more details checkout : [Official help on the issue](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Ubuntu_on_the_Panda_Board)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat " Then you should just connect your Keyboard and HDMI display to the board." -->Is the essential part of the solution. The user is just checking is serialport and not the HDMI display. Official help is mentioned for extra references.

Comment: Please try to include some of those extra solutions as well. Sometimes, your solution will work, but it won't for others (especially if the link goes down). It's best to have all possible troubleshooting methods displayed here in brief.